# For python I want to make each values in a list respond to another value

Tags: python, types

```
def data_entry(categories):

# these are the values within categories
data_entry(['movies', 'sports', 'actors', 'tv', 'games', \
    'activities', 'musicians', 'books'])

# for each different value in categories i need it to open a different txt file
# for example
when categories = movies ([0])
filename='movies.txt'

when categories = sports([1])
filename='sports.txt'
```

How would i write this in code?

Comment: `file_names = dict((x, x + '.txt') for x in data_entry)`?

Answer (score 3):

1. Write a dict that maps a category name to a filename.
2. Loop over your list of categories, and retrieve the filename by indexing into the dict using the category name.
3. Use `open()` with the filename.

Example:

```
categories = ["movies", "tv"]

# long winded:
filenames = {
    "movies": "movies.txt",
    "tv": "television.txt",
    # ...
}

# alternatively:
filenames = dict([(x, x + ".txt") for x in categories])

for category in categories:
    with open(filenames[category], 'rb'):
        pass
```

Comment: And it looks like you can simply build the dict by adding '.txt' to all the keys.  So `dict((i, '%s.txt' % i) for i in ['movies', 'sports', ...)`

Comment: @ bradley. just wondering what does the pass mean? and also does it matter that the file gets opened up within the data_entry function?.. idn if you will get what i mean haha

Answer (score 3):

If you the names of the text files are always going to be `<categoryname>.txt` I would simply do:

```
for category in categories:
    with open(category + ".txt", 'r') as f:
        # Do whatever you need to here...
        pass
```

This of course does not take directories or anything else into account.  If the names of files for each category are likely to change then I'd suggest using a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want a dictionary / hash:

```
dic = { 'movies':'movies.txt', 'xxx':'xxx.txt' }
for key,value in dic.items():
    print (key, value)
```

Comment: `for`, not `foreach`.  Also you can iterate keys and values at the same time: `for k,v in dic.values(): print(k,v)`

Comment: @Steve Howard I think you meant dic.items()?

Comment: I did.  I fixed that while playing with it in the interpreter, then posted the wrong thing anyway. ;)